# which regular expression should i use?

Tags: php, regex, split

If this is my string : "blablabla (blablabla)". 
Which regular expression should i use to split the string in such a way that i get returned:

1. "blablabla"
2. "(blablabla)"

Btw, I want to use the function mb_split.

**EDIT**
The string can alsob be "blablabla blablabla blablabla (blablabla).
explode() wouldn't work because of this.

**EDIT**, this is what i use now:

for example, $name = "blabla blabla blabla blabla (blabla)";

```
$name = explode(' ', $name);
$last = array_pop($name);
$sentence = null; 
foreach ($name as $names) {
$sentence .= $names.' ';
}
$sentence = mb_substr($title, 0, -1, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: What did you try? plzsendtehcodez questions are not what we want on this site.

Comment: You say that explode won't work. But have you tried it? The docs doesn't say that it will just split once, but it will split anywhere it finds a match. http://lv.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: I mean with that, Then I have an array with lots of different keys. So I don't know how to get the values I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're matching on a space that is followed by a '(', the pattern on which to split can be:

```
\s(?=\()
```

Answer (score 9):

Actually, you do not need regex to do such easy task as splitting two words by space. Use `explode()` instead

```
$string = "blablabla (blablaba)";
explode(" ", $string);
```

Answer (score 7):

No regular expression at all, just use `explode`:

```
$mystring = "blablabla (blablaba)";
$mywords = explode(" ", $mystring);
```

All you're doing is looking for a space!

Answer (score 1):

```
explode(" ", $string);
```

you dont required to write Regular Expression.

for EXPLODE

first argument will be neddle by which you want to export string into array..and second argument must be string ..

Answer (score 1):

I would use explode, because no regex is needed here. If you still want mb_split, you can split at anything that is assumed a whitespace (newline, linebreak, space, tab etc): `mb_split("\s", "hello world")`.

Look at [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php). (I actually pasted the example here :))